# Correct Hystersis

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a temperature reading that fluctuates. Is the logic chain below correct to prevent boundary switching on and off?

```
 if (temp > 50)   {
     AC = 100%
 } else if (temp > 40 && temp < 50) {
     null; // change nothing
 } else if (temp > 30 && temp < 40) {
     AC = 50%
 }  else if (temp > 20 && temp < 30) {
     null;
 } else if (temp > 10 && temp < 20) {
     AC = 25%;
 } else if (temp < 5) {
    AC = 0%; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `NULL` macro do here?
Leave that `if` body empty or write a `;` (like I did).

If I were you, I would like to include such temperatures as `40`, `30`, `20` and `10`.
Also it isn't clear why you omit temperatures `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`.

With a little change, the logic must be correct:

Say, if `temp` is 27, it will discard all <50, then <40, then <30 and then when it discards all <20, it figures out that 27 is in range *[20 .. max]*. But there's no need in all these `&& temp < 50` - you have already verified `temp` if it is more than 50 and got a negative result for `27` (in previous *if* condition), so you don't heave to do it again.

```
 if (temp >= 50)   {
     AC = 100%
 } else if (temp >= 40) {
     ;                     // change nothing
 } else if (temp >= 30) {
     AC = 50%
 } else if (temp >= 20) {
     ;
 } else if (temp >= 10) {
     AC = 25%;
 } else {                  // temp may be -1, take this into consideration.
     AC = 0%; 
 }
```

Comment: You are still missing `50`. I'd suggest removing the expressions after the `&&` altogether, as they are taken care of by the previous `if`s